# Load Multiple Images in Android

Tags: android

After calling an API, I get a response of some hundreds of images in the BASE64 format in JSON and I will display them in recyclerview using Glide. Is it an efficient way to get all images in one response and show all images in recyclerview in one shot or do I ask backend developer to send fixed number of images in one response say 10-15 and again make a request when all images are loaded in recyclerview using pagination. Please suggest some best way.

Comment: Pagination is best way... load more images on pull to down

Comment: It is very bad idea to send hundreds of images in BASE64 in single API call. It will be very difficult to handle so much of data. You may see out of memory error. My suggestion is to change the API to get single image per hit.

Comment: API with pagination.. not paginate from mobile.. you need to provide an API able to call by page..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why you store image in BASE64 format on server. change api response and use image url instead of Base64 string. Use picasso for display image in recycleview with resize image.

Add pagination in server api for improve app performance.

Answer (score 0):

It is better to use pagination in RecyclerView so that the user doesn't have to wait for a long time.

Answer (score 0):

You should use pagination to load the data faster and save data. Apart from that if you are using Glide then you dont need the Base64 of image, The url of the image will be enought to diplay the images in the recyclerview.

Answer (score 0):

That will use a lot of memory. Besides, loading hundreds of image will takes longer time, more data and also reduce performance.

Instead of doing that, you can load data from the data source using a `load more`. If the user wants to load more data then load more data using `pagination`.